# Rails 4.2 Query 3 models and belongs_to and has_one cannot get parent based on child attribute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 models with the following relationships:

**EndUser**

```
class EndUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :account, :dependent=>:destroy
```

**Account**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :api_key
```

**ApiKey**

```
class ApiKey < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :account
```

In console I have been trying to do  grab an `EndUser` based on an `ApiKey`'s property `access_token` using this ORM query: `EndUser.joins(:account).joins(:api_key).find_by(access_token:'9b3322aff14d38046f32de9c79ed8273')` *Don't get excited this is not production*

The output from console says `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'api_key' was not found on EndUser; perhaps you misspelled it?` But `api_key` IS and association on account. How do I tell Rails that I am looking for it to join `Account` on `ApiKey` not `EndUser` on `ApiKey`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are nested joins so include them in the same call to `joins`:

```
EndUser.joins(:account => :api_key).find_by(:api_keys => {:access_token => '9b3322aff14d38046f32de9c79ed8273'})
```